# asp.net mvc set textbox value from value in url without jquery or javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, input, textbox, query-string

I have a textbox inside a form tag like this:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "email", @aria_describedby = "emailHelp", @text=Request.QueryString["Email"], @value=Request.QueryString["Email"] })
  <label>Email</label>
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "float:right;" })
```

Now here is the trick... I have an url that goes like this:

```
example.com/Registration?Email=someemail@example.com
```

Now I'm trying to set the value of my textbox automatically by setting the value like this:

```
@text=Request.QueryString["Email"], @value=Request.QueryString["Email"]
```

But this doesn't works... The textbox is still empty after the page is loaded...
And I have looked into the html for example and I can see for example text attribute of my input text tag being set to `someemail@example.com`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Anyone guys? =)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a way to do it. Turns out this is the valid way to do it:

```
 public ActionResult Registration()
        {
            var regViewModel = new UserRegistrationViewModel { Email = Request.QueryString["Email"] };
            return View(regViewModel);
        }
```

Comment: or you could have done `public ActionResult Registration(string Email)` and used `Email` inside the action